# Is there a Skyve method that returns the current version?

Tags: skyve

I understand the version of Skyve was removed from the UI for security reasons but is there a Skyve method that returns the currently running version that we can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UtilImpl.SKYVE_VERSION returns the current version of Skyve.